# Having a 3 way in mongoid — A has_many B, A has_many C, B has_manyC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Here is the situation

- User has_many Posts
- User has_many Replies
- Post has_many Replies

Problem is when I add new reply using

```
@reply = current_user.posts.find(params[:post_id]).replies.new(params[:reply])
```

In the Replies it only saves the `post_id` and `user_id` is `null`, and if I used `current_user.replies.new(params[:reply])` to save the post I get `user_id` but `post_id` becomes `null`

So how to add a reply to have reference for both `post_id` and `user_id`? Anyone got a clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your association like this:

**User Model**

```
has_many :posts
has_many :replies
```

**Post Model**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :replies
```

**Reply Model**

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

So, you can find a post:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

Add new reply to post:

```
@reply = @post.replies.build(params[:reply])
@reply.user_id = current_user.id
@reply.save
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this is far fetched but is there by any mean another way to make it more dynamic, maybe something to setup from the model?

Comment: What do you want setup from the model?